# Django mapping urls to views

Tags: python, django, url

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playground/urls'
I am going through the ultimate django series by mosh hamedani and i came across a problem. I did exactly as he did and it didn't work for me. Here are my urls.py and installed apps.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'playground'
```

]

playground/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

    #URLConf
    urlpatterns = [
        path('hello/', views.say_hello)
    ]
```

storefront/urls.py

```
"""storefront URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('playground/', include('playground/urls'))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe using include('appname.urls')

change

```
path('playground/', include('playground/urls'))
```

to

```
path('playground/', include('playground.urls'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 path('playground/', include('playground.urls'))
```

Insteed of:

```
 path('playground/', include('playground/urls'))
```

You can check that part on [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/)

Hope that help you !

Answer (score 0):

if you post what the terminal gives you that's also sometimes is helpful, as i understand it The Model Does not exist,

try
python mange.py makemigrations

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).